# PHP's mail function doesn't send email

Tags: php

So when I submit my form, everything is stored in the database just fine, I had a really simple email that basically consisted of, 'Hey thanks, this is your link' kind of deal and I received that just fine. But now I've upgraded to using an HTML body instead and suddenly I'm not receiving the email, any idea why?

```
$to = $username;
$subject = 'Thanks for Registering on Dota Pub Stars!';
$message = '<html>
                <head>
                    <title>Registration Successful!</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://www.sithhappens.net/css/style.css" />
                </head>
            <body class="bodybg">
                <div id="registrationform">
                <p class="success">Thanks for registering on Dota Pub Stars!</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <a class="button2" href="http://www.sithhappens.net/?key=' . $activation_key . '&amp;username=' . $username . '&amp;email=' . $email1 . '">Activate Account</a>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: $from\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Are you using this on a live server? Local servers require a tie in with an email server to be able to send mail.

Comment: @cbronson yes I am, I just don't want to release the link cause I'm not ready for the world to see it yet :D

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: you sure that $username is a valid email address ?

Comment: @AyeshK Yes, and also yes, for debugging I echo'd the username and crossed that off the list :)

Comment: check the mailog. it will contain the error.

Comment: @DaniloKobold using Hosting24, I don't think they let me check that log :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your above code workin fine i check like this try to check **$username** value is email

my example

```
$to = 'rsharma@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Thanks for Registering on Dota Pub Stars!';
$message = '<html>
                <head>
                    <title>Registration Successful!</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://site...net/css/style.css" />
                </head>
            <body class="bodybg">
                <div id="registrationform">
                <p class="success">Thanks for registering on Dota Pub Stars!</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <a class="button2" href="http://www.site...net/activateacc.php?key=345345&amp;username=435345&amp;email=34534534">Activate Account</a>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

also check your SMTP settings is ok

Comment: Well thanks for that, at least you helped narrow it down to just my $username, I don't really know who to give answer to, I guess you can have it :D Thanks, I'll work this mess out. And before I even submit, I know what I did wrong, I used $username instead of $email1, you ever have those moments where you think, maybe I should have went to bed 30 minutes ago? Well I just had one.

Answer (score 0):

Your server may be cAse-SEnSitive... also, add the From

```
   $headers="From: $from\r\n";
   $headers.="Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\n";
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I did what you said, still nothing, you can see how I have it in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the trailing comma ',' from the end of $to

it should be `$to = $username;`

and make it sure $username is email address

Comment: try to see the logs to check if the server is producing any exception on the same. May be there is a problel with the smtp in the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try seperating the headers by `\n` instead of `\r\n`, do not mix them and do not include one at the end of the header string.